# why a just opened AI file need to be saved before closing without doing any changes?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, save

I am working in a very regular AI file, it have no variables or any external links. each time I open that file in illustrator, I see an asterisk beside its name tab in my workspace, which mean the file is unsaved and need to click on save button to get rid of that asterisk. 
it is not a big issue specially the file open with no problem. but why it happened?

Comment: I don't think anyone here can tell you. Clearly something in the file is changing when you open it.

Comment: Are you fonts installed on the machine?

Comment: even you Mr. Scott !!! :)

Comment: yes Matt, all my fonts are installed font windows folder.

Comment: Screen size different making the document artboard a difference scale or position? Those things are saved with a document as well.

Comment: have a look at the Edit->Undo menu, it usually shows the name of the last thing that was done...ie "Undo Move"

Comment: @CarlosCanto thanks for the tip, but nothing shows in that menu. dimmed!

Comment: do you have any Third Party Plugins installed that may be updating XMP data?

Comment: yes I have, but nothing wrong with other files I created. this behavior occurred only in just one file.